# Trying to copy the data from an excel file based on the fields required in my input file. But getting #NUM! error in dataframe instead of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to copy the data from an excel file based on the fields required in my input file. But continuously getting #NUM! error printed all over my output dataframe. Any way to solve this and get the original data in the data frame that I want? Tried quite a few things like error handling but the output isn't changing.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
import openpyxl
import re
import xlsxwriter

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter

# Read configuration from config file
config_file = 'myconfig.py'
config = {}
exec(open(config_file).read(), config)

# Set the current working directory to the downloaded folder path
downloaded_folder_path = config['downloaded_folder_path']
os.chdir(downloaded_folder_path)

# Read input file
input_file = config['input_file']
inputs = pd.read_excel(input_file, header=None)

# Read key and output dataframe
key = inputs.head(2)
output_df = inputs.iloc[2:].copy()
output_df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
output_df.columns = output_df.iloc[0]

# Get all filenames in the data_folder_name into filenames list
data_folder_name = config['data_folder_name']
mypath = os.getcwd() + os.sep + data_folder_name
filenames = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

# Process each row in the output dataframe
for i in range(1, len(output_df)):
    symbol = str(output_df["File Name Input"][i])  # Read company name into symbol

    # Find filenames which match with the symbol
    matching_files = [f for f in filenames if symbol.lower() in f.lower()]

    # Amongst the matching files, find the file which is latest
    latest_modified_time = 0
    latest_file = ""
    for matching_file in matching_files:
        filepath = mypath + os.sep + matching_file
        ti_m = os.path.getmtime(filepath)
        if ti_m > latest_modified_time:
            latest_file = matching_file
            latest_modified_time = ti_m

    # Record name of the latest file and its last modified time
    output_df.at[i, "File Name"] = latest_file
    output_df.at[i, "Update Date"] = time.ctime(latest_modified_time)

    if latest_modified_time > 0:  # If some matching file was found for the symbol
        latest_filepath = mypath + os.sep + latest_file
        one_pager = pd.read_excel(latest_filepath, config['one_pager_sheet'], engine="openpyxl", header=None)
        output_df.at[i, "Company Ticker"] = one_pager.iloc[0, 1]

        # Process the columns in the key
        for j in range(1, len(key.columns) - 2):
            column_type = key.iloc[0, j]
            column_value = key.iloc[1, j]

            if column_type == "Pickup":
                field_name, year = [x.strip() for x in column_value.split(",")]
                row1 = one_pager.loc[one_pager[1] == field_name]
                column1 = one_pager.filter(regex=year)

                if not (row1.empty or column1.empty):
                    value = column1.iloc[row1.index[0], 0]
                    if pd.notnull(value) and pd.to_numeric(value, errors='coerce') != "#NUM!":
                        output_df.at[i, output_df.columns[j]] = pd.to_numeric(value, errors='coerce')
                    else:
                        output_df.at[i, output_df.columns[j]] = float('nan')

            elif column_type == "Formula":
                new_dict = {m: output_df.loc[i, m] for m in output_df.columns}
                formula = re.sub(r'{(.*?)}', lambda x: str(new_dict[x.group(1)]), column_value)
                try:
                    result = eval(formula)
                    if isinstance(result, (int, float)):
                        output_df.at[i, output_df.columns[j]] = result
                    else:
                        output_df.at[i, output_df.columns[j]] = "#NUM!"
                except NameError:
                    output_df.at[i, output_df.columns[j]] = "#VALUE!"
                except Exception as e:
                    output_df.at[i, output_df.columns[j]] = "#FORMULA_ERROR"

# Output the dataframe to output file
output_file = config['output_file']
output_df.to_excel(output_file, header=False, index=False)

# Write the dataframe to a new workbook
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_file, {'nan_inf_to_errors': True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for r_idx, row in enumerate(dataframe_to_rows(output_df, index=False, header=False)):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write(r_idx, c_idx, value)

workbook.close()

print("Task completed successfully!")` here
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example